# ¿Como puedo recoger datos de una consulta dinamica c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy buscando ayuda en una solución, espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo una consulta que me devuelve columnas dinámicamente puede ser 5, 6 o n cantidad de columnas y de distintos nombres, mi inconveniente es que no encuentro como recibir esas columnas en c#, es decir leerlas con un READER o lo que se tenga que usar.
El procedimiento normal es poner el nombre de la columna y recibir el valor pero al ser dinámico(cambie de nombre o cantidad de columnas), no se exactamente como hacerlo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es en un procedimiento normal pero al ser dinámico como tendría que hacerlo ?, alguna sugerencia de como solucionarlo ?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Interesante. Voy a **asumir** que reader es un `SqlDataReader` (por eso es importante pegar el código relevante **como texto**). El objeto `SqlDataReader` tiene una propiedad llamada `FieldCount`, que contiene el número de columnas del `ResultSet`. Puedes hacer un ciclo `for` desde `0` hasta `FieldCount`, y obtener el nombre de la columna con `reader.GetName(int columnIndex)`. Luego utilizas el `GetOrdinal` para obtener el valor. Vas a necesitar una lista de `Tuple<T1,T2>`, o un `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, para guardar los pares (columna,valor).

Comment: Arriel gracias por la respuesta, hasta lo que comentas esta bien pero ahora necesito asignarle ese valor que viene de la BD a una entidad que tenga el mismo nombre de columna, como adjunte en la imagen : 

indice = DReader.GetOrdinal("servicio");
 if (!DReader.IsDBNull(indice)) rListadoProveedor.servicio = DReader.GetString(indice);

el nombre de la columna que recojo de la BD es igual al nombre de la entidad del que le asigno, me podras ayudar con eso ?

Comment: Eso ya es otra pregunta. Lo que debes hacer es, mediante `Reflection`, buscar dentro de la entidad una propiedad cuyo nombre sea igual a lo que viene de `reader.GetName()`, y luego setearle el valor por medio de `SetValue()`. Ex: `var miClase = new ClaseBase(); var prop = miClase.GetType().GetProperty(nombreColumna); if (prop!=null) prop.SetValue(miClase, valorColumna);`